# Slider stuck on first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, yii, anythingslider

I used Anythingslider in my script , it's work with all browsers (FF ,IE) but not working 
with Chrome and stuck in first slide.

I just change in code to add  cute  bar  and this is my code :

Widget  View:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/anythingslider.css">    
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>


    <!-- Define slider dimensions here -->
    <style>


    /*** Set Slider dimensions here! Version 1.7+ ***/
/* added #slider li to make panels the same size in case "resizeContents" is false */
#slider {
    width: 715px;
    height: 230px;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -60px;
  direction: ltr;


}
.anythingSlider {
display: block;
overflow: visible !important;
position: relative;
}
#nav-slider {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -20px;

}
#nav-slider ul, #nav-slider span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.3px;
}
#nav-slider li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
}

#nav-slider a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 10px;

    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    font-size:20px;
}
#nav-slider a:hover { }
#nav-slider a.cur { }
#nav-slider a.start-stop { }
#nav-slider a.start-stop.playing {}



    </style>

        <!-- AnythingSlider initialization -->
    <script>
        // DOM Ready
        $(function(){       

$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    startText           : "<img src='<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ; ?>/images/play.png'>",   // Start button text 
    stopText            : "<img src='<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ; ?>/images/puss.png'>",    // Stop button text 
   forwardText         : "<img src='<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ; ?>/images/prv.png'>", // Link text used to move the slider forward (hidden by CSS, replaced with arrow image) 
   backText            :"<img src='<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ; ?>/images/next.png'>" , // Link text used to move the slider back (hidden by CSS, replace with arrow image) 
    // A HTML element (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode) to which the controls will be appended if not null
    appendBackTo: $('#nav-slider span:eq(0)'),
    appendControlsTo: $('#nav-slider span:eq(1)'),
    appendForwardTo: $('#nav-slider span:eq(2)'),


    // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    navigationFormatter: function(index, panel) {
        // This is the default format (show just the panel index number)
        return "" + index;
    }
});



});
    </script>






    <!-- END AnythingSlider -->


      <div class="my_footer_block_trainer" >
         <h1 style="text-align: right;">أخبار المدرب</h1>


                <div id="slider">

                <?php 

                $i=3;
                foreach($newse as $value):?>

              <?php if($i % 3==0):?>
              <div>
              <?php  endif;   ?>    
        <table  width="200px"  style=" display:inline;

margin:0;
padding:.9em;
zoom: 1;


 ">
    <tr >
        <td width="200px" style="text-align:center ;">

       <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/news_images/".$value->t_img,$value->title,array('width'=>'182px','heghit'=>'182px','style'=>'display: inline-block;'));  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200px" style="text-align:right ;">

<div class="title" style="display: inline-block;"> <?php echo  CHtml::link($value->title.$i,array('site/news','id'=>$value->news_id));?></div>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200px" style="text-align:center ;">
        <div class="date" style="display: inline-block;">
                <div class="date" style="display: inline-block;"><?php echo $value->p_date ; ?></div>
        <p>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>



            <?php $i++;?>  
              <?php if($i % 3 ==0):?>
              </div> 

              <?php   endif;   ?>


            <?php endforeach ;?>
                    </div>     
          <br />
           <?php  echo CHtml::link("مركز الاخبار",array('site/newslist'),array('class'=>'reg-now')); ?>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div id="nav-slider">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

</div>
<br /><br />

            </div>
```

this test link : 
http://t.illaf.net/new/trainers/117

Comment: On my chrome it works after pressing start button

Comment: yes it's work but you didn't note how it's stuck on first slide ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the slider is stuck on the first slide is because it is set up to work with a LTR page.

So to make it properly work with a RTL page, you'll need to set the `playRtl` option to `true` ([docs](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Slideshow-Options#playrtl-false)). This option does several things.

1. Adds a `rtl` class name to the outer AnythingSlider wrapper which then applies the following css (the first part is what will fix the slider; the rest is optional and can be removed from the anythingslider.css file)

   ```
   /* slider autoplay right-to-left */
   .anythingSlider.rtl .anythingWindow {
       direction: ltr;
       unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
   }
   /* move nav link group to left */
   .anythingSlider.rtl .anythingControls ul { float: left; }
   /* reverse order of nav links */
   .anythingSlider.rtl .anythingControls ul a { float: right; }
   /* move start/stop button - in case you want to switch sides */
   .anythingSlider.rtl .start-stop { /* float: right; */ }
   ```
2. In older versions of AnythingSlider, the slider arrows also reversed the direction of the image sliding, including the slideshow; but this was changed recently (see [issue #526](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/issues/526)).

This option still needs some work (again, see the issue linked above), so if all you want to do is just make the slider work and not change the arrow direction or the slideshow, then use this code to only apply the class name ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5594/))

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    playRtl: false,
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
        slider.$wrapper.addClass('rtl');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mottie but not worked , but  I guess your idea is true , so I will change  and develop my code to work related to your idea   .